# Ajax pagination filter is not working when click on back button

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter, pagination

I have crearted ajax pagination in my codeigniter project.
It's filtering data using search, checkbox, and dropdown.
everything is working if I am using pagination links so far.
But, For example, when I am on detail page and clicking back button, it's is not keeping the changes. it's going back to default.
How can i keep the filter changes when i press back button from detail view.

Here is my code.
ajax pagination

```
<?php  if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Ajax_pagination{
var $base_url        = '';
var $total_rows      = '';
var $per_page        = 10;
var $num_links       =  2;
var $cur_page        =  0;
var $first_link      = 'First';
var $next_link       = '&#187;';
var $prev_link       = '&#171;';
var $last_link       = 'Last';
var $uri_segment     = 3;
var $full_tag_open   = '<div class="pagination">';
var $full_tag_close  = '</div>';
var $first_tag_open  = '';
var $first_tag_close = '&nbsp;';
var $last_tag_open   = '&nbsp;';
var $last_tag_close  = '';
var $cur_tag_open    = '&nbsp;<b>';
var $cur_tag_close   = '</b>';
var $next_tag_open   = '&nbsp;';
var $next_tag_close  = '&nbsp;';
var $prev_tag_open   = '&nbsp;';
var $prev_tag_close  = '';
var $num_tag_open    = '&nbsp;';
var $num_tag_close   = '';
var $target          = '';
var $anchor_class    = '';
var $show_count      = true;
var $link_func       = 'getData';
var $loading         = '.loading';

/**
 * Constructor
 * @access    public
 * @param    array    initialization parameters
 */
function CI_Pagination($params = array()){
    if (count($params) > 0){
        $this->initialize($params);        
    }
    log_message('debug', "Pagination Class Initialized");
}

/**
 * Initialize Preferences
 * @access    public
 * @param    array    initialization parameters
 * @return    void
 */
function initialize($params = array()){
    if (count($params) > 0){
        foreach ($params as $key => $val){
            if (isset($this->$key)){
                $this->$key = $val;
            }
        }        
    }

    // Apply class tag using anchor_class variable, if set.
    if ($this->anchor_class != ''){
        $this->anchor_class = 'class="' . $this->anchor_class . '" ';
    }
}

/**
 * Generate the pagination links
 * @access    public
 * @return    string
 */    
function create_links(){
    // If our item count or per-page total is zero there is no need to continue.
    if ($this->total_rows == 0 OR $this->per_page == 0){
       return '';
    }

    // Calculate the total number of pages
    $num_pages = ceil($this->total_rows / $this->per_page);

    // Is there only one page? Hm... nothing more to do here then.
    if ($num_pages == 1){
        $info = 'Showing : ' . $this->total_rows;
        return $info;
    }

    // Determine the current page number.        
    $CI =& get_instance();    
    if ($CI->uri->segment($this->uri_segment) != 0){
        $this->cur_page = $CI->uri->segment($this->uri_segment);   
        // Prep the current page - no funny business!
        $this->cur_page = (int) $this->cur_page;
    }

    $this->num_links = (int)$this->num_links;
    if ($this->num_links < 1){
        show_error('Your number of links must be a positive number.');
    }

    if ( ! is_numeric($this->cur_page)){
        $this->cur_page = 0;
    }

    // Is the page number beyond the result range?
    // If so we show the last page
    if ($this->cur_page > $this->total_rows){
        $this->cur_page = ($num_pages - 1) * $this->per_page;
    }

    $uri_page_number = $this->cur_page;
    $this->cur_page = floor(($this->cur_page/$this->per_page) + 1);

    // Calculate the start and end numbers. These determine
    // which number to start and end the digit links with
    $start = (($this->cur_page - $this->num_links) > 0) ? $this->cur_page - ($this->num_links - 1) : 1;
    $end   = (($this->cur_page + $this->num_links) < $num_pages) ? $this->cur_page + $this->num_links : $num_pages;

    // Add a trailing slash to the base URL if needed
    $this->base_url = rtrim($this->base_url, '/') .'/';

    // And here we go...
    $output = '';

    // SHOWING LINKS
    if ($this->show_count){
        $curr_offset = $CI->uri->segment($this->uri_segment);
        $info = 'Showing ' . ( $curr_offset + 1 ) . ' to ' ;

        if( ( $curr_offset + $this->per_page ) < ( $this->total_rows -1 ) )
        $info .= $curr_offset + $this->per_page;
        else
        $info .= $this->total_rows;

        $info .= ' of ' . $this->total_rows . ' | ';
        $output .= $info;
    }

    // Render the "First" link
    if  ($this->cur_page > $this->num_links){
        $output .= $this->first_tag_open 
                . $this->getAJAXlink( '' , $this->first_link)
                . $this->first_tag_close;
    }

    // Render the "previous" link
    if  ($this->cur_page != 1){
        $i = $uri_page_number - $this->per_page;
        if ($i == 0) $i = '';
        $output .= $this->prev_tag_open 
                . $this->getAJAXlink( $i, $this->prev_link )
                . $this->prev_tag_close;
    }

    // Write the digit links
    for ($loop = $start -1; $loop <= $end; $loop++){
        $i = ($loop * $this->per_page) - $this->per_page;    
        if ($i >= 0){
            if ($this->cur_page == $loop){
                $output .= $this->cur_tag_open.$loop.$this->cur_tag_close; // Current page
            }else{
                $n = ($i == 0) ? '' : $i;
                $output .= $this->num_tag_open
                    . $this->getAJAXlink( $n, $loop )
                    . $this->num_tag_close;
            }
        }
    }

    // Render the "next" link
    if ($this->cur_page < $num_pages){
        $output .= $this->next_tag_open 
            . $this->getAJAXlink( $this->cur_page * $this->per_page , $this->next_link )
            . $this->next_tag_close;
    }

    // Render the "Last" link
    if (($this->cur_page + $this->num_links) < $num_pages){
        $i = (($num_pages * $this->per_page) - $this->per_page);
        $output .= $this->last_tag_open . $this->getAJAXlink( $i, $this->last_link ) . $this->last_tag_close;
    }

    // Kill double slashes.  Note: Sometimes we can end up with a double slash
    // in the penultimate link so we'll kill all double slashes.
    $output = preg_replace("#([^:])//+#", "\\1/", $output);

    // Add the wrapper HTML if exists
    $output = $this->full_tag_open.$output.$this->full_tag_close;
    ?>
    <script>
    function getData(page){  
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo $this->base_url; ?>"+page,
            data: { page: page },
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('<?php echo $this->loading; ?>').show();
            },
            success: function(data){
                $('<?php echo $this->loading; ?>').hide();
                $('<?php echo $this->target; ?>').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
    <?php
    return $output;
}

function getAJAXlink($count, $text) {
    $pageCount = $count?$count:0;
    return '<a href="javascript:void(0);"' . $this->anchor_class . ' onclick="'.$this->link_func.'('.$pageCount.')">'. $text .'</a>';
}
}
```

Controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Posts extends CI_Controller {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('post');
    $this->load->library('Ajax_pagination');
    $this->perPage = 2;
}

public function index(){
    $data = array();

    //total rows count
    $totalRec = count($this->post->getRows());

    //pagination configuration
    $config['target']      = '#postList';
    $config['base_url']    = base_url().'posts/ajaxPaginationData';
    $config['total_rows']  = $totalRec;
    $config['per_page']    = $this->perPage;
    $config['link_func']   = 'searchFilter';
    $this->ajax_pagination->initialize($config);

    //get the posts data
    $data['posts'] = $this->post->getRows(array('limit'=>$this->perPage));

    //load the view
    $this->load->view('posts/index', $data);
}

function ajaxPaginationData(){
    $conditions = array();

    //calc offset number
    $page = $this->input->post('page');
    if(!$page){
        $offset = 0;
    }else{
        $offset = $page;
    }

    //set conditions for search
    $keywords = $this->input->post('keywords');
    $sortBy = $this->input->post('sortBy');
    if(!empty($keywords)){
        $conditions['search']['keywords'] = $keywords;
    }
    if(!empty($sortBy)){
        $conditions['search']['sortBy'] = $sortBy;
    }

    //total rows count
    $totalRec = count($this->post->getRows($conditions));

    //pagination configuration
    $config['target']      = '#postList';
    $config['base_url']    = base_url().'posts/ajaxPaginationData';
    $config['total_rows']  = $totalRec;
    $config['per_page']    = $this->perPage;
    $config['link_func']   = 'searchFilter';
    $this->ajax_pagination->initialize($config);

    //set start and limit
    $conditions['start'] = $offset;
    $conditions['limit'] = $this->perPage;

    //get posts data
    $data['posts'] = $this->post->getRows($conditions);

    //load the view
    $this->load->view('posts/ajax-pagination-data', $data, false);
}
}
```

view script

```
<script>
function searchFilter(page_num) {
page_num = page_num?page_num:0;
var keywords = $('#keywords').val();
var sortBy = $('#sortBy').val();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>posts/ajaxPaginationData/'+page_num,
    data:'page='+page_num+'&keywords='+keywords+'&sortBy='+sortBy,
    beforeSend: function () {
        $('.loading').show();
    },
    success: function (html) {
        $('#postList').html(html);
        $('.loading').fadeOut("slow");
    }
});
}
</script>
```

Comment: By "back button" you mean browser back button then you'd have to store all the relevant variables in a session variable...

Comment: Did you have a chance to look at my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially what we need to do is modify some logic/add some so that each of the variables `page`, `sortBy` and `keywords` are stored in a session variable when they are posted from ajax so that when we leave the page and come back our pagination is the same. In such a case, all that is required is to provide an AJAX call to `ajaxPaginationData` with empty post data:

```
function ajaxPaginationData() {

    $this->load->library('session'); // if you haven't already
    $conditions = array();
    // Page (offset)
    $page = $this->input->post('page');
    if (!empty($page)) {
        $offset = $page;
        $this->session->set_userdata('se_page', $page);
    } elseif ($this->session->has_userdata('se_page')) {
        $offeset = $this->session->se_page;
    } else {
        $offset = 0;
    }

    // Keywords and Sortby
    $keywords = $this->input->post('keywords');
    $sortBy = $this->input->post('sortBy');
    if (!empty($keywords)) {
        $conditions['search']['keywords'] = $keywords;
        $this->session->set_userdata('se_keywords', $keywords);
    } elseif ($this->session->has_userdata('se_keywords')) {
        $conditions['search']['keywords'] = $this->session->se_keywords;
    }
    if (!empty($sortBy)) {
        $conditions['search']['sortBy'] = $sortBy;
        $this->session->set_userdata('se_sortby', $sortBy);
    } elseif ($this->session->has_userdata('se_sortby')) {
        $conditions['search']['sortBy'] = $this->session->se_sortby;
    }

    // total rows count
    $totalRec = count($this->post->getRows($conditions));

    // pagination configuration
    $config['target'] = '#postList';
    $config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'posts/ajaxPaginationData';
    $config['total_rows'] = $totalRec;
    $config['per_page'] = $this->perPage;
    $config['link_func'] = 'searchFilter';
    $this->ajax_pagination->initialize($config);

    //set start and limit
    $conditions['start'] = $offset;
    $conditions['limit'] = $this->perPage;

    //get posts data
    $data['posts'] = $this->post->getRows($conditions);

    //load the view
    $this->load->view('posts/ajax-pagination-data', $data, false);
}
```

Comment: I did tried above changes into my code, but for example when I am sorting it, and coming back from visiting one of the link in sorted element it's not showing any post.

Comment: sorry for late reply. @Alex

Comment: $page = $this->input->post('page');
        if(!$page){
   if($this->session->has_userdata('se_page')){
    $offset = $this->session->se_page;
   }
   else{
    $offset = 0;
   }
   
        }else{
            $offset = $page;
   $this->session->set_userdata('se_page', $page);
        }

Comment: I tried to change little bit for the first if else. It's is working fine, but. It's adding one more page into my pagination. for example. If I am on page 6 and after visiting a link from it, it is adding page 6 as page 1 of my pagination and directing me on it. so, in total I have two copies of same page.

Comment: I just noticed an error in my code `$offeset = $this->session->se_page;` should be `$offset` ... maybe you caught it already.

Comment: //calc offset number
        $page = $this->input->post('page');
        if(!$page){
   if($this->session->has_userdata('offset')){
    $offset = $this->session->userdata('offset');
    
   }
   else{
    $offset = 0;
   }
   
        }else{
            $offset = $page;
   $this->session->set_userdata('temp_'.$offset);
        }

Comment: interesting solution i guess. glad it is working for you! if my answer helped feel free to upvote! you can also post an answer to your own question ;)

Comment: Actually, it's not working. I got the result because of previously stored session data. @alex